# meet "called object is not a function" error when use macro to Initialization tree data

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I want to implement the Lisp Cons type in C, so I use link list to achieve it.

At the same time, I use a lot of macros to simpilfy the data creation.

The code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Macro Utils
 */

#define create_m(type) ((type *) malloc(sizeof(type)))
#define new_m(type, ...) ({ \
  type * __t = create_m(type); \
  *__t = (type){ __VA_ARGS__ }; \
  __t; })

/*
 * Type Define
 */

typedef struct atom Atom;
enum ATOM_TYPES;

// Cons Type
typedef Atom * Cons[2];

#define car(c) (c[0])
#define cdr(c) (c[1])
#define new_cons_m(car, cdr) ({ \
  Cons * __c = create_m(Cons); \
  car(__c) = car; \
  cdr(__c) = cdr; })

// Id Type
typedef char * Id;

#define new_id_m(id) (strdup(id))

// Container Type
enum ATOM_TYPES {
  ATOM_CONS, ATOM_ID
};

struct atom {
  enum ATOM_TYPES type;
  union {
    Cons value_cons;
    Id value_id;
    void * value;
  };
};

#define new_atom_m(t, ...) (new_m(Atom, .type = t, __VA_ARGS__))
#define new_atom_cons_m(car, cdr) ( \
  new_atom_m(ATOM_CONS, .value_cons = new_cons_m(car, cdr)) )
#define new_atom_id_m(id) ( \
  new_atom_m(ATOM_CONS, .value_id = new_id_m(id)) )

int main() {
  printf("start program\n");
  Atom * test = new_atom_cons_m(
    new_atom_id_m("lisp"),
    new_atom_cons_m(
      new_atom_id_m("log"),
      new_atom_id_m("say hello")
    )
  );
  return 0;
}
```

And it failed to compile, with the following log:

```
arane.c: In function ‘main’:
arane.c:16:27: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
 #define new_m(type, ...) ({ \
                           ^
arane.c:18:18: note: in definition of macro ‘new_m’
   *__t = (type){ __VA_ARGS__ }; \
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
arane.c:68:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘new_atom_m’
   new_atom_m(ATOM_CONS, .value_cons = new_cons_m(car, cdr)) )
   ^~~~~~~~~~
arane.c:68:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘new_cons_m’
   new_atom_m(ATOM_CONS, .value_cons = new_cons_m(car, cdr)) )
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~
arane.c:92:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘new_atom_cons_m’
   Atom * test = new_atom_cons_m(
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
arane.c:66:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘new_m’
 #define new_atom_m(t, ...) (new_m(Atom, .type = t, __VA_ARGS__))
                             ^~~~~
arane.c:70:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘new_atom_m’
   new_atom_m(ATOM_CONS, .value_id = new_id_m(id)) )
   ^~~~~~~~~~
arane.c:93:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘new_atom_id_m’
     new_atom_id_m("lisp"),
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

...and much more errors
```

I think it is because there are some expressions in function call's argument list. I am seeking for some way to solve it, I use gcc7.5 to finish my work, if needed, I can upgrade it.

-----------2022-01-24-14:15-----------

The problem is solved, with some twest in code, however, I still don't really understand how it was happend.

The code changed as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * Macro Utils
 */

#define create_m(type) ((type *) malloc(sizeof(type)))
#define new_m(type, ...) ({ \
  type * __t = create_m(type); \
  *__t = (type){ __VA_ARGS__ }; \
  __t; })

/*
 * Type Define
 */

typedef struct atom Atom;
enum ATOM_TYPES;

// Cons Type
typedef Atom * Cons[2];

#define car(c) (c[0])
#define cdr(c) (c[1]) // deletes here

// Id Type
typedef char * Id;

#define new_id_m(id) (strdup(id))

// Container Type
enum ATOM_TYPES {
  ATOM_CONS, ATOM_ID
};

struct atom {
  enum ATOM_TYPES type;
  union {
    Cons value_cons;
    Id value_id;
    void * value;
  };
};

#define new_atom_m(t, ...) (new_m(Atom, .type = t, __VA_ARGS__))
#define new_atom_cons_m(car, cdr) ( \
  new_atom_m(ATOM_CONS, .value_cons[0] = car, .value_cons[1] = cdr) )
#define new_atom_id_m(id) ( \ // changes here
  new_atom_m(ATOM_CONS, .value_id = new_id_m(id)) )

int main() {
  printf("start program\n");
  Atom * test = new_atom_cons_m(
    new_atom_id_m("lisp"),
    new_atom_cons_m(
      new_atom_id_m("log"),
      new_atom_id_m("say hello")
    )
  );
//   Atom * test = new_atom_cons_m(NULL, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the command line you're using to compile the code?  Is one of the options `-ansi`?  You're using C99 or later features, and `-ansi` means `-std=c89` (aka `-std=c90`).  You're also using a GCC extension with the `({…})` notation.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I use this `clear && gcc arane.c -o arane && ./arane` to compile and run, with no flags. I will have a try with it :) .

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are trying to solve with this, but it is likely not the correct solution since the code is cryptic to read. You should look for ways to simplify it and perhaps use private encapsulation of that struct in a separate .c file.

Comment: As for gcc version it should be fine long as `--version` is at least 5.0.0 and you have no problem with using non-standard gcc extensions.